# Increase java heap space in Linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, heap-memory

If I run:

```
ps -aux | grep java
```

I can see something set as

```
 -Dblackduck.serverFileURL=file:///protextsoftwarescan1/project/ -server -Xmx76800m -Xms76800m -XX:PermSize=192m -XX:+UseG1GC
```

Now, how to find and edit the `Xmx` and `Xms` for this particular variable?

Comment: How do you launch this process ? If it is a service maybe you can check in init.d directory the script that launch the service.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you launch the process. 
If it is a shell script, look for parameters.
Or maybe, it is an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

process initialization scrips are usually held in "/etc/rc...". You should find the process script blackduck or whatever the program name is and edit the values of -Xmx and -Xms there.